# Logback multiple configuration error on multiproject Junit4/Eclipse/Gradle

Tags: java, logback, slf4j

I've got a Java Eclipse/Gradle multiproject build build that uses SLF4J/Logback in the client, server, and a couple of libraries.  I cannot figure out how to manage my Logback configurations in a way that permits sane Junit4 testing without generating the error

`Resource [logback-test.xml] occurs multiple times on the classpath.`

My configuration files look like this:

```
project
  server
    config/logback-dev.xml
    src/main/resources/logback.xml
    src/test/resources/logback-test.xml
  client
    config/logback-dev.xml
    src/main/resources/logback.xml
    src/test/resources/logback-test.xml
  library
    src/test/resources/logback-test.xml
```

- Production config `logback.xml` for each distribution module goes in `src/main/resources`.  It gets added to the build, and ends up in the jar.  This seems necessary, because Logback's database appender is part of the application, and I need a default log configuration that includes it.
- Development config `logback-dev.xml` lives in `module/config`.  I specify its location as a VM argument in eclipse: `-Dlogback.configurationFile=config/logback-dev.xml`
- In theory, my unit tests should all use `logback-test.xml`, which should live in `module/src/test/resources` for each module.

It's that last point that's the problem.  Running a Junit4 test on a module with dependencies will pick up it's `src/test/resources/logback-test.xml`... but will also pick up the logback-test.xml that eclipse has placed in the `module/bin` of each dependency.  Logback gets loaded before JUnit runs any user code, so programmatic solutions won't work.

I have dozens of Junit4 classes that I want to run in Eclipse.   I'd rather not get stuck manually specifying VM args for each of several dozen Junit run configurations in Eclipse.

How can I avoid the `multple logback.xmls` error for my unit tests without manually configuring every JUnit class?

Comment: If you've found the solution by now, please post it

Comment: Sorry, I am no longer actively coding, and I don't remember if I solved this.